# How does one audit changes in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

How does one properly *track* state in a typical MySQL database?

I.e. answer questions like the history of a particular row in a table.

1. When it was changed
2. What was changed
3. Who changed it over time.

I was hinted by a colleague that "key exchanges" were used to solve this problem but I am bit confused how to realise this practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways one can do auditing. Although I am not familiar with key exchanges in relation to database auditing, these are the methods I am familiar with:

**MySQL Enterprise Audit**

https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/audit.html has official documentation. There's a blog that describes Enterprise Audit with some examples that might help you. https://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/installing-and-testing-the-mysql-enterprise-audit-plugin/

**History tables**

One of the ways I have audited tables is by creating history tables of a similar structure as the base table and put triggers in place to write old data to this table before writing new data to the base table. An additional date/time column to store date when record was archived additionally helped with queries.

For example, `sale_order` table had a `sale_order_history` table.

**Audit table**

A single audit table with columns such as Action (i.e. Insert, Update, Delete), Archived (date/time), Archiver (who caused this record to be archived), Tablename and clob/blob to store original data as a JSON or binary data. This would be a single table in which archived data from multiple tables would pour in. Depend on the volume of change, this table can become really big.

**Stream data to another DB**

Another model I have seen, but not done myself, is pushing the old data into a message queue (e.g. RabbitMQ). Subscribers to the queue write data to an archive table that's held separate from the original database. This method keeps the original database instance lean but creative queries would have to be written to diff data. Application layer wrote the audits, which didn't please the DBAs.

Comment: Enable the binary log. Its probably the lowest overhead to install and contains the most detail of changes (especially in `binlog_format=row/mixed`). Lacks tracking to application code (unless comments are put in SQL identifying their location).

Comment: The binlog feature on AWS RDS at least requires me to download a large changelog within 24hrs. Once I have the mysql-bin-changelog.XXXXXX whatever, I have yet to find tools to sanely help me parse and use that file @danblack.